# Finding index of fibonacci number with 1000 digits (PE #25)

Tags: java

I've got two algorithms for printing the first fibonacci number with 1000 digits, but it seems I am missing out something.

`Algo 1`

```
public class ab{
public static void main(String[] args){
     float phi = (float) 1.618033989;
     float curr = 1;
     float noOfDigits = 0;
     float ans;
     float fiveSqrt = (float) Math.sqrt(5);
    while(noOfDigits< 1001){
        noOfDigits = (curr*Math.log10(phi)) - Math.log10(fiveSqrt);
        System.out.println("curr : " + curr + "Digits : " + Math.round(noOfDigits));
    curr++;
    }
}
}
```

`Output`

Its output it quite long but in the end it reads :

```
curr : 4781.0Digits : 999
curr : 4782.0Digits : 999
curr : 4783.0Digits : 999
curr : 4784.0Digits : 999
curr : 4785.0Digits : 1000
curr : 4786.0Digits : 1000
curr : 4787.0Digits : 1000
curr : 4788.0Digits : 1000
curr : 4789.0Digits : 1000
curr : 4790.0Digits : 1001
```

It seems, 4785 is the answer, but snap! its incorrect.So I tried a more mathematical approach by solving the Wolfram equation in reverse.

```
ans = (1000 + (float) Math.log10(fiveSqrt))/ (float) Math.log10(phi);
System.out.println(ans);
```

Output : `4786.6445`
Again, the same. Am I missing something out?

Comment: Ermm ... perhaps the want the >>value<< of the smallest Fibonacci number with 1000 digits ...

Comment: Do you need the Fibonacci number or the ordinal of that number?

Comment: Why do you believe that this equation will give you a fibonacci number with a certain number of digits?  I remember computing fibonacci numbers recursively - not with a single, simple equation such as # of desired digits added to a constant.  I don't see how this could work, but this is not a math site.  You might try http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Oh yes @StephenC, my bad

Comment: @StevenHansen , Because it's the golden ratio that is mathematically proven.

Comment: @MayurKulkarni More reason for you to ask your question in a mathematical way on a math site.  It looks like you have a general programming understanding - my guess is your math is suspect.

Comment: @StevenHansen that's because I believe perhaps I m messing up with conversions, maybe double-float might be eating up few decimals, I suspect.

Comment: to get float use `1.618033989f`. `(float)1.618033989` is 1) longer 2) may not result in the correctly rounded value due to double rounding, as `1.618033989` is a double constant, it'll be rounded to double precision first then rounded again to float, which may not be the closest value in float

Comment: and always default to `double` unless space is a concern. `float` can only be precise to ~7 digits and is not enough in most operations

Comment: `Math.log10(fiveSqrt)` and `Math.log10(phi)` don't change through the whole program, why don't store them as constants instead of calculating again and again like that

Comment: how many decimal digits does a number have if it's log10 is 1.6? How many when it is 4786.6?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Nice suggestion, taken into account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [this](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html#logs) tutorial to get the complete understanding. You misinterpreted the algorithm, you have used `Math.round(noOfDigits)` which is incorrect, what you should be doing is:

1. Calculate the noOfDigits, as you do in your algorithm
2. Extract the integer part.
3. Add '1' to it.

   ```
   long roundedNumber;
   while(noOfDigits< 1001){
   noOfDigits = (curr*Math.log10(phi)) - Math.log10(fiveSqrt);
   roundedNumber = (long)noOfDigits + 1;
   System.out.println("curr : " + curr + "Digits : " + Math.round(roundedNumber));
   curr++;
   }
   ```

   Which gives me the answer : `4782.0` Which is correct.